# Frictional Force on Plane Increases when Angle Increases?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

I came across this question in one of my books and don't completely understand the answer: An object is resting on a board. One side of the board is slowly raised, up to an angle of 60 degrees. The object does not slide. The questions asks if, as the board is being raised, the frictional force increases or decreases. My reasoning for the force of friction decreasing is that as the angle between the horizontal and the board increases, the normal force decreases (Force of friction = μmgcos(θ).

The answer/explanation in the book, however, states that since the object does not move, the frictional force is equal to the component of gravity parallel to the board (which obviously increases as the board is raised). Is this correct? And if so, how can one reconcile this with the normal force decreasing?

Answer (score 3):

As long as the object does not slide, the static frictional force is equal to $mg\sin \theta$.  Once the frictional force also becomes equal to the normal force $mg\cos \theta$ times the coefficient of static friction, the object begins to slide.  But the static friction law is *an inequality*, not an equality.  $$F\leq \mu_s N$$  As long as the F is less than $\mu_sN$, the object won't slide.  The static friction coefficient only tells you the value of the friction force at the point where the object is just **on the verge** of sliding.

Comment: This helps but I am a little confused about the mgsinθ part. Frictional force must equal the coefficient of friction (whether static or kinetic) * Normal Force. In the context of this question, does that mean as long as the object is not moving mgsinθ = μs* mgcosθ?

Comment: No, the *maximum* static friction is equal to coefficient times normal force.Friction is sneaky;  it adjusts itself, within limits, to the necessary amount.  Your car, standing still, on level ground with no one pushing on it, has *zero* friction force acting on it.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I am getting confused because the angle is changing. After θ > 45 degrees mgsinθ >μmgcosθ. How can μmgcosθ be the maximum static friction?

Comment: In this situation, $\mu mg \cos \theta$ is the maximum value that the static friction force $mg\sin \theta $ can have at angle $\theta$ if  the object is not to start to sliding.  If $mg\sin \theta < \mu mg \cos \theta $, the object won't slide.  If $mg\sin \theta = \mu mg \cos \theta $, the object is on the verge of sliding.  So, the critical angle for starting to slide  is  $\theta = \arctan \mu$.  If the angle is smaller than this, the object won't slide.  But the static friction force at all angles up to this point is $mg\sin \theta $.

Answer (score 0):

One way of looking at this arrangement is to consider the external force $F_{\text{ext}}$ which must be used to prevent an object of mass $m$ moving.

When the object is on level ground $F_{\text{ext}} = 0$

When the object is on an inclined plane, angle $\theta $ with the horizontal, the magnitude of the external force on the object has to be $mg \sin \theta$ but up the slope.

When on level ground the maximum static frictional force is $\mu_s mg$ but the actual static friction force required to stop the object moving is zero.

As the angle $\theta$ is increased the force needed to stop the object from moving $mg \sin \theta$ increases.
So the static frictional force must also increase but this will be less than the maximum possible static frictional force at that angle which is $\mu_s mg \cos \theta$.

So as the angle of the slope increases the maximum static frictional force decreases but as long as this is greater than the component of the weight of the object down the slope, the object will not move.

There comes an angle $\theta_c$ where the the component of the weight has increased so much that the maximum frictional force is just equal to the component of the weight.

$$ \mu_s m g \cos \theta_c - mg \sin \theta_c = 0 \Rightarrow \mu_s = \tan \theta_c$$

It is certainly true that for this condition the normal force on the object is smaller than for smaller angle $\theta$ and so the maximum possible static frictional force is also smaller as is shown in the graph below.

[image]

However as long as the maximum static frictional force is greater than the component of the weight of the object down the slope, the object will not slide down the slope.